# How to track all file changes in Git for auditing purposes

Tags: git, devops

We have several developers pushing code to our master repository. For auditing purposes, I have to log all file changes to a CSV file for weekly/monthly review. I know you can go through the file change history, but this file needs to be emailed out to the team.

Does anyone know how I can do this.

We are using Azure DevOps if this matters.

The expected output should be a line-by-line list of changes with the before and after, e.g:

```
string hello = "Hello"
string hello = "hello world"
```

First line is before, second line is after commit.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide the expected output of the program. Please consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help others answering your question.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is by tagging the repo weekly/monthly and taking the diff between the tags.  [see this documentation](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/inspecting-a-repository/git-tag) to know more about tagging. And [this one](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-diff) to know about diff

For example, if you want weekly diff.  tag weekly by using the command

`git tag <tagname>`    (`git tag 04-12-2019` )

And to see the diff between two tags (say between `04-12-2019` and `11-12-2019`)
use the command

`git diff 04-12-2019  11-12-2019`

You can also use git log to see the log between tags 
eg : `git log 04-12-2019  11-12-2019`

To take the changes in a particular file, use

`git diff 04-12-2019  11-12-2019 -- some/file/name`